# I want to seed my database with a json file using postgre with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, postgresql

### SOLVED USING

`path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets','cards.json')`
as the path for the file to read.

### ORIGINAL QUESTION

I have a Json file and I want to use the data to create Ruby objects in my database.

I tried to use this in my seed.rb but it won't open the json.
Is there a better approach to what I am trying to do?

```
#seeds.rb

require 'json'

cards = JSON.parse(File.read('cards.json'))

cards["cards"].each do |card| 
    Card.create(card)
end
```

running rails db:seed

`Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - cards.json`

Answer (score 1):

You need to give correct directory of your file.